# Solve system of two equations in Android / java

Tags: java, android

I have two equations (Distance and slope of a line formula)

d = sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 )
m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

Known: d, m, x1, y1
Unknown: x2, y2

The problem is the distance equation isn't linear...

Is there a way to code this in java (using Android compatible libraries) to solve? I tried doing simple guessing but it is too slow.

Thanks

**EDIT: Code for triangle**

```
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gp2, p2);

        Point p3 = new Point();
        double slope = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
        double x = 0;
        if (p2.y - p1.y >= 0 && p2.x - p1.x >= 0) {
            x = - Math.sqrt(600 / (1 + slope*slope)) + p2.x;
        } else if (p2.y - p1.y >= 0 && p2.x - p1.x < 0) {
            x = Math.sqrt(600 / (1 + slope*slope)) + p2.x;
        } else if (p2.y - p1.y < 0 && p2.x - p1.x >= 0) {
            x = - Math.sqrt(600 / (1 + slope*slope)) + p2.x;
        } else if (p2.y - p1.y < 0 && p2.x - p1.x < 0) {
            x = Math.sqrt(600 / (1 + slope*slope)) + p2.x;
        }
        double y = -slope*p2.x + slope*x + p2.y;

        p3.set((int) x, (int) y);

        double inverseSlope = 0;
        if (slope == 0) {
            inverseSlope = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            inverseSlope = -1 / slope;
        }

        x = -Math.sqrt(300 / (1 + inverseSlope*inverseSlope)) + p3.x;
        y = -Math.sqrt(300 / (1 + inverseSlope*inverseSlope))*inverseSlope + p3.y;

        Point p4 = new Point();
        p4.set((int) x, (int) y);

        x = Math.sqrt(300 / (1 + inverseSlope*inverseSlope)) + p3.x;
        y = Math.sqrt(300 / (1 + inverseSlope*inverseSlope))*inverseSlope + p3.y;
        Point p5 = new Point();
        p5.set((int)x, (int) y);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
        path.moveTo(p4.x, p4.y);
        path.lineTo(p5.x, p5.y);
        path.moveTo(p5.x, p5.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

It appears it is being caused by slope is always an integer so when it is < 1 it is 0 which is not good...

Comment: Your parenthesis don't match, do you mean: sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2) * m = (y2-y1)/(x2 -x1)

Comment: please don't change your question after having the answer accepted, just start a new question next time ...

Comment: alright, so here's some code that does what you actually want to: http://studio.sketchpad.cc/WjZ7UqIq4F
when you deal with orientation in space it's generally a bad idea to use slopes because you will have to deal with all the corner cases (infinite and zero) explicitly most of the times. think in terms of vectors - ie points, angles and distances - instead. it will simplify your equations on paper _and_ the resulting code. if you look at my code youll see it doesn't use anything besides the pyhthagorean theorem and the fundamental definition of the sinus. a final thought:name your variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review the algebra below:

Define

x = x2-x1

and

y = y2-y1

Then

m * x = y

and

d^2 = x^2 + m^2 * x^2 = (1 + m^2) * x^2

Therefore

x = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2))

then

x2 - x1 = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2))

so

x2 = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2) + x1

Similarly

y = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2)) * m

y2 = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2)) * m + y1

**So the answer is:**

x2 = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2)) + x1

y2 = sqrt(d^2 / (1 + m^2)) * m + y1

Answer (score 2):

the "library" you're looking for is called mathematics :)

you can ask wolfram alpha: 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+d+%3D+sqrt%28+%28x2+-+x1%29%5E2+%2B+%28y2+-+y1%29%5E2+%29%2C+m+%3D+%28y2+-+y1%29+%2F+%28x2+-+x1%29+over+the+reals
(don't ask me why it knows x2 and y2 are interresting)

you *can* do such things by hand, but be very careful not to drop signs. even though this stuff is taught in school they have little respect for detail. note that in this case there are two possible solutions and you need ensure that d > 0 in all cases!

[image: First solution]
[image: Second solution]

Comment: So basically I'm using these formulas to draw a triangle: I've edited my question to show the code i use to draw it. It draws it well except for when the slope of the line is < than a certain amount, then the triangle isn't being drawn. Any ideas why the triangle isn't being drawn?

Comment: well, there's more problems with the code. try out this interactive version to see what i mean: http://studio.sketchpad.cc/WjZ7UqIq4F . the problem is that slope is ill-defined if the x-coordinates line up, because you basically divide by zero. (i'll post something constructive in a sec)

Comment: Sorry for not posting a new question - and ya i noticed that and fixed it, but the slope is 0 when really the slope is like 0.9 i'm guessing because of precision.